# jQuery UI Datepicker blurry when on certain months

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When my datepicker is on certain months that force it to be 6 blocks high, the text blurs. 
When on months that are 5 or less blocks high, it is clear. 
When I say 'blocks', I mean the chart grid height. 

I am calling the datepicker method on a DIV element. Here is the code :

```
$("div.date").datepicker({
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: 0,
     onSelect: function (date) {
        alert(date);
     }
});
```

Is there anything in the default jquery ui css file that would prevent this? 
I am currenly using a custimized file. I will post it if this issue can't be resolved without it. It's just a bit long.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more then a vague explanation? An example containing code maybe?

Comment: @empiric Added code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the parent container. Using `transform:translate(-50%, -50%);`

Not sure why this is causing problems.
Fixed it by using `transform:translate(-50.1%, -50.1%);` on the parent and `left:49.9%` `top:49.9%`.

Wish I knew why this issue occurs.